# simplest way to enable / disable control, based on status of other controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am tinkering with a C# Windows application. I have a button that I want to disable when there is nothing selected in a nearby listbox, or when all the text is removed from some textbox. Surely the opposite enabling actions have to occur. Also, these enabling / disabling actions have to be undertaken when the tab comes in display, when currently loaded data change, and so on.
I find it very easy to write `MyButton.Enabled = (currentproject != null) && (MyTextBox.Text != String.Empty) & (MyListBox.SelectedIndex > -1)`, but I think there is something wrong if I have to write it repeatedly in MyListBox_SelectionChanged, MyTextBox_ TextChanged, and in a few other places. Is there a property of the button where I could put that code, and let the button watch itself?

Comment: You don't want the `Button` to watch __itself__, you want it to watch some __other__ controls; so this idea won't work. But Peter shows the way: create a `SetButtonState` function to call on their relevant events and you don't have any real code duplication..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something somewhere needs to react to changes to the properties the button state depends on. So code like what you describe has to exist in some fashion *somewhere*.

That said, like any other code, it's possible to reuse the specific logic. You don't need to literally rewrite the expression in multiple places. Instead, put it in a method somewhere, and then call that method from the various event handlers that are invoked when the properties the state depends on change.

An alternative would be to define a property that itself represents the button state, and then use data binding to bind your button's state to that property. At the top level, this may be a little cleaner. But IMHO it's not much of an improvement, because you still need to subscribe to the various property-changed events in order to correctly update that new property. I.e. you're still doing the same basic thing. It's just been abstracted a bit in that case.